# AndroidStudio: How to see contents of built-in theme

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

I'm using a built-in theme with AndroidStudio, namely, in my manifest, I use

```
android:theme="@android"style/Theme"
```

This seems to work fine, but I'd like to know exactly what attributes are included in that theme (for my education and possible modification). How can I examine this theme?

Comment: I haven't examined like this before. However, if I had to, I would click on the `Theme` holding the `Cntrl` button pressed.

Comment: See? DontPanic.

Comment: Works great! Thanks.